# How powerful(in terms of output watts)can current Gunn diodes get?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, microwave

That is, if I wanted a Gunn diode in the low GHz range with a 20kW output does such a device exist? If not what kind of semiconductor materials would be needed to support ballistic transport at high voltages?

Comment: why 20kW?   that is a lot of power, particularly for a single device

Comment: From /wiki/Gunn_diode. "Gunn diodes are used to build oscillators in the 10 GHz to high (THz) frequency range." Maximum output is typically a few watts, even as a amplifier.

Comment: When you get into the kW GHz realm, people tend to go for vacuum tubes instead as scaling the power is as easy as building a bigger tube (well sort of), some single klystrons can pump out megawatts at a time. I've not seen an *individual* RF semiconductor that could do more than 1kW and that was a big power mosfet at only a couple hundred MHz (usually several are stringed together for more power)

Answer (score 2):

Basically no,

The Gunn diode is also known as a transferred electron device and relies on scattering to populate a tertiary band. The up shot is that this device needs to be biased to operate in it's negative resistance range. A lot of power can go into this biasing and indeed Gunn diodes are often heavily heat-sinked to be able to handle the power reliably at low oscillation power.

In short these devices are used to create oscillation, the power amplification step is seperate.

Comment: Klystron tubes are often used as microwave power amplifiers with a wide frequency range and power levels up to at least 1.5 megawatts. Depends on your needs and your budget.